# Agregar vectores a una matriz en java

Tags: java

estoy tratando de agregar vectores a una matriz String[][] tabla; el vector es un array de strings que es igual a una sola entrada separada por guiones("-") usando String.split, esto con el fin de crear una tabla en la que cada entrada sea una fila, trato de hacerlo con un loop for pero me da un error "Index 1 out of bounds for length 1" creo que es por que el numero de filas es menor que el numero de columnas(que es constante 7), pueden darme alguna solucion?

```
 static String[][] tabla;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int numFil = lector.nextInt(); 
        
        tabla = new String[numFil][7];

        for(int i=0; i<numFil; i++){ 
            String[] lectura = lector.nextLine().split("-");
            for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[0];
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[1];
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[2];
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[3];
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[4];
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[5];
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[6];

            }

        }
        for(int i=0; i<tabla.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
                System.out.println(tabla[i][j]);
            }
        }
        lector.close(); 
        }
```

Comment: De donde obtienes el valor de numPac, que no lo muestras en el código

Comment: Perdon se me olvido modificarlo, numPac es numFil

Comment: Sea como sea, tendrías que basar el `for`  anidado en el tamaño que tenga `lectura`. No puedes dejar la decisión del número de iteracciones a un valor arbitrario, pues si el usuario escribe más o menos palabras con el separador, tendrás error en el código.

Comment: Lo puse como una constante por que se que las entradas siempre van a ser 7 strings, de todas maneras le puse "lectura.length" y aun asi me sale ese error, creo que es por que el numero de filas puede ser menor que el de columnas(lectura.length)

Comment: Desconozco el motivo del código, pero creo que deberías de mostrar un mensaje previo de lo que pides y como lo pides con un System.out.print("Ponga número de filas");, es que acabo de intentar probar tu código y claro, se queda esperando, pero no sabes el que.

Comment: Si yo se que se queda esperando la entrada pero es que es para entregar a una plataforma automática que ingresa el número una vez encuentra el  Scanner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando codifiques trata de mostrar el mensaje de lo que tiene que digitar el usuario al menos para que veas en que punto del programa te encuentras.
Hay un error muy común que cometen al leer datos por teclado y que también cometiste en tu código: Cuando vas leer un dato de tipo `int` luego vas leer un dato de tipo `String` no hagas lo siguiente:

```
int datoEntero=leer.nextInt();
String datoString=leer.nextLine();
```

Nos dará error porque falta limpiar el buffer de entrada de java.
Una de las formas correctas de leer es:

```
int datoEntero=Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine());
String datoString=leer.nextLine();
```

Ahora yendo a tu código, declaras una matriz con una columna fija de longitud 7, entonces si digitan una cadena separados por `-` y tiene menos de 7 palabras nos dará un error de longitud y si la cadena tiene más de 7 palabras solamente se guardará en la matriz las 7 primeras palabras. (no se si siempre vas querer ingresar una cadena de longitud 7).
**Disculpen la muletilla con el 7**

He modificado un poco tu código sin variar lo que quieres inicialmente.

```
static String[][] tabla;     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese número de Fila: ");
        
        int numFil = Integer.parseInt( lector.nextLine());         
       
        tabla = new String[numFil][7];

        for(int i=0; i<numFil; i++){ 
            System.out.print("Ingrese el string: ");            
            String[] lectura = lector.nextLine().split("-");            
            for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
                tabla[i][j] = lectura[j];
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<tabla.length;i++){
            System.out.println("\n\tFILA: "+(i+1));
            for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
                System.out.println(tabla[i][j]);
            }
        }         
    }
```

Al correr el programa obtendremos

```
Ingrese número de Fila: 2
Ingrese el string: uno-dos-tres-cuatro-cinco-seis-siete
Ingrese el string: ocho-nueve-diez-once-doce-trece-catorce

    FILA: 1
uno
dos
tres
cuatro
cinco
seis
siete

    FILA: 2
ocho
nueve
diez
once
doce
trece
catorce
```

**EDIT**
Te dejo una solución con `ArrayList` para que no tengas el error al escribir una cadena con longitud menor a 7

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<List<String>> tabla = new ArrayList<>();
        
        System.out.print("Ingrese número de Fila: ");        
        int numFil = Integer.parseInt( lector.nextLine()); 
        
        for(int i=0; i<numFil; i++){ 
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.print("Ingrese el string: ");            
            String[] lectura = lector.nextLine().split("-");            
            for (String lectura1 : lectura) {
                temp.add(lectura1);
            }
            tabla.add(temp);
        }
        
        for(List tablaTemp:tabla){
            List<String> aux = tablaTemp;

            for(String s : aux){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! soy nuevo en java, la clase Array no tiene un metodo parecido a Array.push() en js sin tener que usar ArrayList?

Comment: Los Array en java son vectores estáticos para agregar elementos se realizan a partir de su índice, el push() es el equivalente al add() de ArrayList